# How to make a prop declaration optional when using "key in SomeType"?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following setup:

```
declare type NetworkName =
  | 'netA'
  | 'netB'
  | 'netC'

enum SupportedAsset {
  ASSETA = 'assetA',
  ASSETB = 'assetB',
  ASSETC = 'assetC',
}

interface OrderStrategy {
  propA: number
  propB: number
  propC: string
}

const defaultSettings: OrderStrategy = {
  propA: 1,
  propB: 0.1,
  propC: 'foo'
}


type Strategies = {
  [key in NetworkName]: {
    [key in SupportedAsset]: OrderStrategy
  }
}

export default {
  netA: {
    assetA: {
      ...defaultSettings,
    },
  },
  netB: {
    assetA: {
      ...defaultSettings,
    },
  },
  netC: {
    assetA: {
      ...defaultSettings,
    },
  }
} as Strategies
```

But I'm getting error that `TS2352: Conversion of type <the exported object> to type Strategies may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. f this was intentional, convert the expression to unknown first.`

However, I don't want to convert to `unknown` first, because I lose the strict typing when I populate the exported object.

What I think the issue is - the compiler forces me to declared each of the `SupportedAsset` inside each `NetworkName` object in the exported `Strategies` object. But I don't want to do that, because some of the strategies must not be supported by the app at a given time. So, essentially, I think I need to change this:

```
type Strategies = {
  [key in NetworkName]: {
    [key in SupportedAsset]: OrderStrategy
  }
}
```

somehow to not force me to declare each key from `SupportedAsset`. How do I do that?

Or is the issue something else?

Comment: Are you really just looking for the `?` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wejnXN)?  If so someone could write up an answer or find a relevant dupe target; if not, what is missing?

Comment: @jcalz, if I add the `?` mapping modifier, then the SupportedAsset keys are not strictly enforced and I can put any key inside the network objects instead of just the supported ones - `assetA`, `assetB`, `assetC`. So, it becomes the same situation as casting to `unknown` first, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Please show me with a [mre] in code, by [edit]ing the question to show the use case you're trying to enforce.  When you use a type assertion (`as X`) then you are intentionally asking the compiler to loosen its type checking.  If you want something else, then maybe you want `satisfies X` (or `satisfies X as X`) instead of `as X` but now the scope of the question seems to be creeping away from "how do I make this optional".